# Add product attributes, From/To, hotel booking

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, orders, product-attribute

I am new to magento and now I have a problem.

*Using Magento 1.9.2.2*

I need to add to the products two date attributes,

> From xxxx/xx/xx
> To xxx/xx/xx

It's for a hotel booking, and yes, the products are hotel rooms.

These attributes need to appear in the product description, and are required to add product to the cart.

It also need to be added and showed up in the order, and so in the order e-mail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy & available in default Magento

- Create two custom options for your product as **From** and **To** & set input type as **date** & set Is Required **Yes**.

  These options will be required to add product to the cart & will also display in order.

Comment: I will try that. Thank You. But my order email are not displaying ordered products, only payment method and customer info. Any clue about that?

Comment: Ordered products in email comes from layout "sales_email_order_items" that is available in layout section. If you using some custom theme set default theme for testing purpose.

Comment: Much thank you! Now another problem, how can I set the 'To' date to be always greater than 'From' Date? Is there a default Magento option to do it?

Comment: No, You could use jQuery for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks again! About the email thing, I have edited it through *app/locale/pt_BR/template/email/sales*, and thats probably the reason the e-mail don't show ordered product, it's not in *order_new.html*, what can I do to solve this? Can you give me the paths?

Comment: Sorry, I will open another question for that.